# How can one add/remove components from a sklearn gmm object for further warm start?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, gmm, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-model

The `sklearn.mixture` object `GaussianMixture` provides the framework to fit a GMM to provided data, but how can one add/remove components from a sklearn gmm object for further warm start?

Answer (score 0):

Given an `np.array` `X`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
```

One can easily fit a GMM to the data with the `.fit()` method:

```
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, random_state=1).fit(X)
```

To change a parameter (e.g. number of components), invoke the `.set_param()` method, set the `warm_start` value to `True`, and change the desired parameter. One can then fit the gmm to the data again, but using the previous fitting as initialization:

```
gm.set_params(warm_start=True)
```